# Join to give list with optional relationship column

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Tables:

```
        users: id INT

        items: id INT
               setid INT

         sets: id INT

relationships: userid INT
               itemid INT
               relationship ENUM('owner', 'participant')
```

Given a `userid` and a `setid`, we need to generate a list of all the items in the set, and the user’s relationship to each item, if a relationship exists. i.e. the results would

```
setid    itemid   relationship
---------------------------------
1        1        NULL
1        2        owner
....
```

The following doesn't work, because the second `where` clause eliminates rows where `relationship` is null:

```
select
    sets.id as setid,
    items.id as itemid,
    relatonships.relationship as relationship

from sets
    inner join items on sets.id = items.setid 
    left join relationships on relationships.itemid = items.id

where
    sets.id = 5
    and relationships.userid = 27
```

However, the second `where` clause eliminates rows where there is no existing relationship between that item and the given user. How can this be done with a single query?

Answer (score 1):

It was very simple, I didn't understand you could test against a constant in a 'join ... on' clause:

```
select
    sets.setid,
    items.itemid,
    relationships.relationship

from sets
    inner join items on items.setid = sets.id
    left join relationships
        on relationships.itemid = items.id
        and relationships.userid = 5
where
    sets.id = 1
```

Comment: Dammit, you took my answer, except that I did away with joining on table `set`.

Answer (score 0):

**Not 100% what you are asking, by try this**

```
select
    sets.id as setid,
    items.id as itemid,
    relatonships.relationship as relationship

from sets
    inner join items on sets.id = items.event 
    LEFT join relationships on relationships.itemid = items.id

where
    sets.id = [say, 5]
    and relationships.userid = [say, 27]
```

Keep in mind that the relationship column will be NULL if none exists.    Also, the relationship reference in the WHERE clause could eliminate rows as well.   Hope this gets you start, again I might misunderstand what you are trying to achieve.   From your table design, there does not seem to be a relationship between the user and the sets, could you possibly the list of fields in the tables.

***Try the following query:***

```
select sets.id as setId,
       items.id as ItemId,
       relationships.relationship
from sets
    join users on 1=1
    join items on sets.id=items.setid
    left join relationships on relationships.itemId = items.id
where 
    sets.id=5 and users.id = 27
```

***By adding the users table to the join with 1=1, you do not need the where clause to reference the relationship table at all***

***Change the left join to:***

```
left join relationships on relationships.itemId = items.id 
AND relationships.userId=users.id
```

Comment: I've added an example to the question. Not sure how to explain it better. Let me know if you have any ideas! Cheers, B

Comment: Sorry Sparky, second answer is v clever, but not the solution. It will include all items for which there is an entry in "relationships" under that itemid, whether or not that relationship pertains to the stated user. EG, if we have a relationship between user 3875 and item 5, that relationship will show up for *any user at all*.

Comment: Change the left join to:

left join relationships on relationships.itemId = items.id and relationships.userId=users.id 

and that should do it for you

Comment: Realised I was being a dummy. The solution's pretty obvious. You don't need to `join users`, just add a second predicate to the left join. Grr!